# Evaluate $\sum_{n=0}^{N-1} \exp(2 \pi \frac{n}{N} i)$

Tags: trigonometry, summation

It is asked to evaluate the sum

$$\sum_{n=0}^{N-1} \exp(2 \pi \frac{n}{N} i)$$

Using Euler's formula, the problem is reduced to evaluate

$$ \sum_{n=0}^{N-1} \cos(2 \pi \frac{n}{N}) \text{ and }\sum_{n=0}^{N-1} \sin(2 \pi \frac{n}{N})$$

But how to evaluate those sums?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You don't want to use Euler formula.

Just observe that

$$\sum_{n=0}^{N-1} \exp(2\pi \frac{n}{N} i) = \sum_{n=0}^{N-1} \left( \exp(2\pi \frac{1}{N} i)\right)^n$$

And you have a geometric sum

$$\sum_{n=0}^{N-1} \left( \exp(2\pi \frac{1}{N} i)\right)^n = \frac{1-\left( \exp(2\pi \frac{1}{N} i)\right)^{N}}{1-\exp(2\pi \frac{1}{N} i)}$$

Comment: Indeed, I didnt note this. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Consider that
$$\xi_n = \exp\left(\frac{2\pi i n}{N}\right) $$
is a root of the polynomial $x^N-1$, hence:
$$ \sum_{i=0}^{N-1}\xi_n = \color{red}{0}$$
follows from [Vieta's formulas](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/VietasFormulas.html).

Answer (score 2):

Hint : it's a geometric series.